# Display Custom Setting from iterated value in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, controller, customsetting

I have a VF page & controller that is querying accounts and putting them into a list, and them displaying the fields Account Name, State,and Last Activity.

I have a custom setting that is a list of zip codes (which is also a field on account) and their corresponding avg per capita income.

I am able to get values from custom settings, but have trouble understanding iterating them to match the account data displayed.

Is using a map the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both your account list and your custom settings list have the zip codes you could use that as the key in a map. Query your custom settings and put them in a map similar to this example.

```
Map<String, Double> zipToCapitaMap = new Map<String, Double>(); //Assuming field types

for(Account a :myListOfAccounts){
    Double avgPerCapita = zipToCapitaMap.get(a.zipcode);
    String myAccountInfo = 'Name '+a.Name+' State '+a.State+' AvgPerCapita '+ avgPerCapita; 
}
```

Double check that your zip codes in the custom settings are exactly as they are on the accounts. No extra white space or quotes.

Comment: marking as the best answer as my custom setting is of the List variety

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to access the custom setting on the page directly and use one of the Salesforce Functions for compare for example:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="a">
    <apex:outputText value="{!a.name}" 
                     rendered="{!CONTAINS(!$Setup.SettingsObject__c.SETTING__c, a.PostalCode})}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Used [`$Setup`](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_setup.htm) global variable here:

> A global merge field type to use when referencing a custom setting of
>   type “hierarchy.”